# How to receive an image through props in react vite

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image, react-props

This code that you can see works if the project was created with create-react-app but instead it throws the following error `"require is not defined"`

```
<img src={require(`../Media/${imagen}.jpg`)} alt={textoImagen}/>
```

If anyone knows a way to receive the images in a similar way please let me know

Comment: Is this image available statically or is it user uploaded in some way?

Comment: they are static images that I have in a folder in the project

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use static imports, but this requires some trickery around getting them to work with a dynamic string as you need.

What you do is import everything in the folder line by line and then you reference those variables using a map. It's quite cumbersome. There are nicer ways to do this in `Vite` for example where you have wildcard require's or if you are in an ejected `create-react-app` setup where you can modify the webpack config.

Create a new file inside of `Media` folder called `index.js` and export every image from it. I have just used some random names by way of example.

```
// These names after the `as` must match the expected string contained within `imagen` for this image.

export { default as image1 } from './image1.jpg'
export { default as image2 }  from './image2.jpg'
export { default as image3 }  from './image3.jpg'
export { default as image4 }  from './image4.jpg'
```

Now in your file where you need to use them do:

```
import * as images from '../Media'

// ...

<img src={images[imagen])} alt={textoImagen}/>
```